# Storing a value in a cookie in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that creates a button and toggles a div.

I would like this div to be togled on or off based on a cookie value. the cookie is updated each time this is toggled. The initial value is the cookie value.

If no cookie is present, one is created with initial value of 'true'. The cookie is_side_toggled is a boolean.

```
function addRightButton() {

    $('.fc-header-right').html
        ('<a class="btn btn-small btn-unscheduled">>></a>');

    if ($('#cal-side').is(":visible")) {
        $('.btn-unscheduled').html('>>');
    }
    else {
        $('.btn-unscheduled').html('<<');
    }

    $('.btn-unscheduled').on('click', function () {

        $('#cal-side').toggle();
        if ($('#cal-side').is(":visible")) {
            $('.btn-unscheduled').html('>>');
        }
        else {
            $('.btn-unscheduled').html('<<');
        }
        resizeCalendar();
    })
}
```

How could I add a bool cookie and get its value?

Thanks

Comment: Have you read documentation on setting/getting cookies w/ JavaScript?

Comment: You should show an attempt before asking a question

Comment: Cookie values are strings, for a bool value you can just use the existence of the cookie, or a value of "0" and "1", or "false" and "true", or whatever you would like.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the jquery cookie plugin at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
and do something like:

```
function addRightButton() {

    if($.cookie('scheduled') == '0'){
        $('.fc-header-right').html('<a class="btn btn-small btn-unscheduled"><<</a>');
        $('#cal-side').hide();
    }
    else
        $('.fc-header-right').html('<a class="btn btn-small btn-unscheduled">>></a>');

    if ($('#cal-side').is(":visible")) {
        $('.btn-unscheduled').html('>>');
    }
    else {
        $('.btn-unscheduled').html('<<');
    }

    $('.btn-unscheduled').on('click', function () {

        $('#cal-side').toggle();
        if ($('#cal-side').is(":visible")) {
            $('.btn-unscheduled').html('>>');
            $.cookie('scheduled','1');
        }
        else {
            $('.btn-unscheduled').html('<<');
            $.cookie('scheduled','0');
        }
        resizeCalendar();
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cookies can be accessed through document.cookie() methood native to JS, if you don;t wish to use a library as jQuery else using jquery, cookies can be accessed/manipulated as [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).
 Please use something like $.cookie('scheduled', true) based on your code

[Edit:] SO didn't show me this ques. is answered and answer above me by @Omar is correct